# Gridview change select row to an image?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Is it possible to change my gridview select column to an image? When a user clicks on select it opens a pdf from the gridview. Is it possible to instead have a small pdf icon instead of a select link? At the same time still be able to call:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your select column to a `TemplateField`, then change the `Button` inside to an `ImageButton`.  Make sure the `Command="Select"` stays, because that's what the GridView uses to fire and handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.